# Write the negation of the following statement (in words):

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

"For any field $F$, and any $a\in F$, if $a^3 = 1$ then $a = 1$."

Is this statement TRUE OR FALSE?

Is the negation TRUE OR FALSE?

Attempt:

There is a field $F$ and there is an $a \in F$ such that if $a^3 ≠ 1$ then $a ≠ 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite: What you need for the negation is

"There is a field $F$ and there is an $a\in F$ such that $a^3 = 1$ and $a\neq 1$."

That is, the negation of $a^3 = 1 \rightarrow a = 1$ is $$\lnot(a^3 = 1 \rightarrow a = 1)\equiv \lnot(a^3 \neq 1 \lor a = 1) \equiv a^3 = 1 \land a \neq 1$$

Comment: is this statement true or false?

Comment: Either the original statement is true (and so the negated statement is false) or else the negated statement is true (and so the original statement is false). What are your thoughts?

Comment: i think the negation is true?

Comment: I think you're right. ;-) For the negation to be true, all you need is existence of a field or of an element in the field in for which the negated statement holds.